# Only allow site url in text field using wp_kses/wp_filter_nohtml_kses?

Tags: theme-options, validation, wp-kses

I'm working on validation for a theme options page.

Is there a built in way to add an argument to wp_kses/wp_filter_nohtml_kses that will allow a specific link to be entered(wrapped in a tags) but not all links?

I only want the user to be able to enter a link to the main site in this particular text field.

Thank You.